# Same dates comparing in Java returning -1

Tags: java, jdbc

```
try {

        String hql = "SELECT taskDate FROM TaskFutureDates t WHERE t.taskId= : taskId";
        List<java.sql.Date> result = em.createQuery(hql).setParameter("taskId", taskId).getResultList();

        java.sql.Date currentDate =new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()); 

        if (result.size() != 0) {

            for(java.sql.Date date: result) {

                if(date.compareTo(currentDate)>=0) {

                   System.err.println("CAST= "+(Date) date);
                    return (java.sql.Date) date;
                }

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

        //System.err.println(e);
    }
    return null;

}
```

when I am comparing the two dates I am getting error scenarios

1.when I am comparing alternative days I am getting -1
eg
   09/04/2020
   10/04/2020

2. when the date is same I am getting -1

   eg 
   10/04/2020
   10/04/2020

in the 2nd scenario, I should get 0 why the result is -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes to retrieve and compare stored date values against today’s date.

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ).isAfter( LocalDate.now( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
```

## Details

As the [correct Answer by Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61137310/642706) explained, you should not be using the terrible class `java.sql.Date`. That class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Specifically, `java.time.LocalDate`.

As of JDBC 4.2, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database. For columns of a type akin to the standard-SQL type `DATE`, use `setObject`, `updateObject`, and `getObject` to exchange `LocalDate` objects.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

To get today’s date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. So while it may be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan, it may simultaneously be “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

If you do not specify a time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone is applied implicitly.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Compare using `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter` methods.

```
Boolean isFuture = ld.isAfter( today ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

from the compareTo doc:

> a value less than 0 if this Date is before the Date argument

today() (= last midnight) or probably any date from your table is less than now() (which includes the current time)

Answer (score 1):

Although `java.sql.Date` is supposed to be a date, it actually is still a thin wrapper around epoch milliseconds. It doesn't truncate them. So two `java.sql.Date` values that are the same date, can still have two different epoch milliseconds values (ie check the `getTime()` result), and as a result they won't compare identical.

The implementation of the `java.sql.Date` constructor (`Date(long)`) is:

```
public Date(long date) {
    // If the millisecond date value contains time info, mask it out.
    super(date);

}
```

Contrary to the comment, nothing is masked out. This is probably because `java.sql.Date` is sensitive to the default JVM time zone, and trying to mask it out would only complicate things.

In any case, since Java 8 / JDBC 4.2, it would be better to use `java.time.LocalDate` instead of `java.sql.Date`.

If you can't fully switch to using `LocalDate`, I would recommend at least using:

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
//...
if (date.toLocalDate().compareTo(currentDate) >= 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Or - as shown in the [answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61143590/466862) - use the specialized comparison methods like [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)), [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)) and [`isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)).